# Question about JS Async / Sync return issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous, return

I need some help about some js async/sync stuff. I read a lot of post, youtube video etc and I don't understand my problem. The problem I've got is I use some async functions which are going to return a value after the processing and use this returned value inside the main function to respond to a get call.

I have a NodeJS Express setup, when I go the the specific link my server received a request and execute a function.

```
server.get('/info', (req, res) => {
    //res.send('Hello this is the API for sysinfo!');
    //res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    console.log(getCpuInformation());
});

function getCpuInformation() {
    si.currentLoad()
    .then(data => {
        var cpuUsage = Math.round(data.currentload);
        console.log(`CPU Usage : ${cpuUsage}%`);
        return cpuUsage;
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error(`Error during the request of the CPU : ${error}`);
    });
}
```

The console.log inside the getCpuInformation is working perfectly because it is waiting the result of the si.currentLoad to write but the console.log inside the server.get write undefined because, I guess, it doesn't wait the return (or the return actually return before the end of si.currentLoad).

Can you help me ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
server.get('/info', async (req, res) => {
    //res.send('Hello this is the API for sysinfo!');
    //res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    console.log(await getCpuInformation());
});

async function getCpuInformation() {
    try {
        const data = await si.currentLoad();
        var cpuUsage = Math.round(data.currentload);
        console.log(`CPU Usage : ${cpuUsage}%`);
        return cpuUsage;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(`Error during the request of the CPU : ${error}`);
    };
}
```

Comment: This is the first thing I tried but you can't use await inside a sync function, doing the same if you add an async function which is called by the server.get and which call the getCpuInformation.

Comment: Correct, which is why it's not a sync function.  Look carefully.  I added the `async` keyword.

Comment: Doesn't change anything, you added the async like I told you on last comment, but the get is still sync (can't use await inside)

Comment: But express allows an async function on a get  I have my own code doing exactly that.  So what is `server` then if it's not an express app?  Your question is tagged with express.  My own code which works just fine is `const app = express(); app.get('/test/', async (req, res) => {`

Comment: You are right, I just forgot to add async on the server.get, my bad, need to sleep I gues ...

Answer (score 0):

So thanks to some of your anwser I changed my code but now I need to figure how after getting the information, send it back to the client who did the request. And the change I made is good or still badly made ?

```
server.get('/info', (req, res) => {
    //res.send('Hello this is the API for sysinfo!');
    getAllInformation((resultReturned) => {
        console.log(resultReturned);
    });
});

async function getAllInformation(myCallBack) {
    var cpuUsage = await getCpuInformation();
    // more inc
    myCallBack(cpuUsage);
}

async function getCpuInformation() {
    try {
        const data = await si.currentLoad();
        var cpuUsage = Math.round(data.currentload);
        //console.log(`CPU Usage : ${cpuUsage}%`);
        return JSON.stringify({ "cpuUsage": cpuUsage});
    } catch(error) {
        //console.log(`Error during the request of the CPU : ${error}`);
        return JSON.stringify({ "cpuUsage": "ERROR"});
    }
}
```

Comment: you dont need both callback and async in `getAllInformation`. either use one or another. if you don't like my answer - see @user2740650

Answer (score -2):

Your `getCpuInformation` function never returns any value.
Line

```
return cpuUsage;
```

is referred to callback function which you pass to `.then` and not to `getCpuInformation` function.

You need to convert `getCpuInformation` to async function/promise or use a callback function like that:

```
server.get('/info', (req, res) => {
    //res.send('Hello this is the API for sysinfo!');
    //res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    getCpuInformation((resultReturned) => console.log(resultReturned));
});

function getCpuInformation(myCallBack) {
    si.currentLoad()
    .then(data => {
        var cpuUsage = Math.round(data.currentload);
        console.log(`CPU Usage : ${cpuUsage}%`);
        myCallBack(cpuUsage);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error(`Error during the request of the CPU : ${error}`);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this information, Your version is working now I need to understand why and how to convert it with await etc

Comment: This answer is only half correct.  The solution here is to just add a `return` so it's `return si.currentLoad().then(...).catch(...)`.  Then `getCpuInformation()` returns its promise and the caller can use `await` or `.then()` on the returned promise to get the desired value.  There's no need for this function to be converted to a callback or even to `async`.

Comment: @jfriend you are wrong. there is a call to `si.currentLoad().then` which is a promise. and the awaited result is inside the promise. that's why author needs to convert it to async/promise/callback

Comment: Yes, `si.currentLoad().then().catch()` returns a promise and that promise needs to get RETURNED from the function so the caller of the function can use the promise to access the resolved value.  You apparently don't understand how you return a promise from a function and let the caller use `.then()` or `await` to get the value out of the promise.  You don't layer a custom callback on top of a promise.  That's an anti-pattern.